# Given $a+b+c$, Can I calculate $a^2+b^2+c^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I want to calculate $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$  when I am given $a+b+c$.
It is known that a,b,c are positive integers.
Is there any way to find that.

Comment: No. Are there any more details given? If $ab + bc + ca$ is given, for example, then you can use the relation $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab + bc + ca)$.

Comment: Is this the original problem, really?

Comment: Did you even try anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Suppose that $a+b+c = 6$.

If $a = b = c = 2$, then $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 12$.

If $a = 4$ and $b = c = 1$, then $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 18$

The sum of the squares varies for a given sum of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Answer (score 4):

If $a+b+c = k$ then $(a+b+c)^2 = k^2 \implies a^2+b^2+c^2 = k^2 - 2(ab + ac + bc)$, hence you would have to know the value of $ab + ac + bc$.